# Redirect iframe from parent page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a doubt, how can I redirect an iframe from his parent page? 
I have this

```
if(($mypassword == "home.guava")) {
    echo "<script>window.top.location.href = \"teste\";</script>";
}
```

in my php file that is attached to the iframe page. But what I need is something like this that will redirect the iframe from the parent page!

Thanks to you all :D

Comment: What are you getting for a while? Some error?

Comment: This isn't Javascript? PHP maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script is in the parent you don't have to have problems.

```
if(($mypassword == "home.guava")) {
    echo "<script>document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = \"teste\";</script>";
}
```

Examples:

```
<body>
  <iframe id="one" src="url"></iframe>
  <iframe id="two" src="url"></iframe>
</body>
```

```
// Parent to child:
document.getElementsById('one').src = url;

// Child to parent
window.parent.location.href = url;

// Child to other child
window.parent.document.getElementById('two').src = url;

// Current (Child or Parent)
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: I can't paste that in the parent, people will be able to see all passwords in F12...

Comment: In php you can work with passwords but never send them. I have modified the answer so that you have all the ways to change an iframe.

Comment: I still can't put it to work... I have this in login.php file:

`if(($mypassword == "test")) {echo "<script>document.getElementsById('one').src = http://localhost/guava/not_connected/list.html;</script>"; }`

Comment: getElementById goes without 's' (My fault), make sure it prints it in the html that comes to you. In other words, it is not a php failure.

Comment: Show the bug you get

Comment: It's not any bug, the page is redirected to the error page that I created:

`else {echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'error.html'</script>";}`

Comment: So it's PHP, remove the redirects and put a "true" or "false" to see where it comes in

Comment: change window.location to alert and see what comes out

Comment: Like this? `else {echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert = 'error.html'</script>";}`

Comment: I just want you to make sure it goes where it needs to go. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert the if alert ("true"); and to the else alert ("false");

Comment: Now both alerts appear, the normal one (password correct) and the error one...

Comment: copy and paste if($mypassword == "test"){echo "<script>alert('true');</script>"; }else{ echo "<script>alert('false');</script>";}

Comment: If there is only one alert it is fine, if you do not have another fault in another part of the code.

Comment: Ok it worked! Now, with that, how can I redirect the iframe?

Comment: if it behaves well it changes the alerts for what you had before. Just a moment.

Comment: `if($mypassword == "test"){echo "<script>document.getElementsById('one').src = http://localhost/guava/not_connected/list.html</script>"; }else{ echo "<script>window.location = 'error.html'</script>";}`

Comment: Make sure to put the ID of your iframe

Comment: When I write "test" password, it redirects me to login.php, not the iframe to the source... I have the iframe with the "one" Id and it's all correct... I even tried without the "s" that you mentioned...

Comment: It does not have 's', failure to copy and paste. If it were javascript fault it would do nothing. You have to have another JavaScript in list.html to get you out. I don't see what else it can be.

Comment: Well, nevermind, we are already writing a lot in the comments... Big thanks to you for trying to help me :)